# does haskell have dependent types?

Tags: haskell

I know Haskell already has the ability to parametrise a type over another type (similar to template programming in C++), but I'm wondering whether Haskell can also parametrise a type over values – whether it supports dependent types. With dependent types, you can have a type that's parametrised over integers, for example vectors of size n, matrices of size n×m, etc.

If not, why not? And is there any possibility that it will be supported in the future?

Answer (score 19):

Haskell doesn't quite have full dependent types, although it can get very close with extensions like `DataKinds` and `TypeFamilies`.  The issue at the moment, as far as I know, is that value-level Haskell has explicit bottoms but type-level Haskell does not.

This doesn't stop you from parametrizing types over other types, *including the `DataKind`-lifting of values*.  As of GHC 7.6, and with `DataKinds` enabled, you can use type-level naturals and strings, as well as type-level tuples, type-level lists, and the type-level liftings of any (non-higher-kinded, non-generalized, non-constrained) algebraic data types, which is similar to (but much more general than) C++'s ability to use integers in templates.

Comment: Do the upcoming changes in GHC 8 add full dependent types?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen Not quite; they enable dependent *kinds*.

Answer (score 8):

To expand a bit on what Ptharien's Flame explained nicely about the current status - and GHC Haskell seems to be moving further in the direction of dependent types (while preserving phase separation) with each version.

So for eg at ICFP 2013 this September, a paper on the next phase of this process should be presented, ["Towards dependently typed Haskell:
System FC with kind equality"](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~eir/pubs.html), about collapsing the kind and type levels. As was [announced to be the plan some 3 years ago](http://byorgey.wordpress.com/2010/08/05/typed-type-level-programming-in-haskell-part-iv-collapsing-types-and-kinds/).

And it even mentions the next step: "We are also aware that [Adam Gundry’s forthcoming dissertation](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/adam.gundry/thesis/) will include Π-types in a version of System FC and we will want to make this feature available in the source language as well. (Personal communication)"

Answer (score 2):

Haskell has traditionally tried to fake it, but the end result is a much larger and seemingly repetitive type system. But this might soon change! See:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O805YjOsQjI
- https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/DependentHaskell
- https://github.com/goldfirere/ghc/